# Mostrar alerta mediante un cuadro de texto en Angular 6

Tags: bootstrap, angular

al ingresar un numero a un textbox quiero que me arroje una alerta, pero no he podido solucionarlo, al ser igual o superior a 30 debe mandar la alerta

en html es mi codigo del textbox

```
<input
   type="number"
   min="0"
   id="obraAv"
   [value]="obraAv"
   (input)="Alert()"
   class="form-control"
   placeholder="Avance de la obra"
   required="required"/>
```

este es el mensaje que quiero mostrar

```
<div *ngIf="showAlert" class="col-md-3 mb-2">
    <div class="alert alert-danger" ng-value="obraAv">
         <strong>Su obra civil no es asegurable</strong>
    </div>
</div>
```

y este es el codigo en ts

```
    showAlert=false;
  obraAv;
  Alert()
  {
      if(this.obraAv==30)
      {
          this.showAlert=true;
      }
      else{
          this.showAlert=false;
      }
  }
```

les agradecere mucho su apoyo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta asignadole un modelo al input utilizando `ngModel` y luego detectamos el cambio de ese modelo con el evento `ngModelChange`:

```
<input
   type="number"
   min="0"
   id="obraAv"
   [value]="obraAv"
   ([ngModel])="obraInput"
   (ngModelChange)="obraChange()"
   class="form-control"
   placeholder="Avance de la obra"
   required="required"/>
```

Entonces en el codigo cuando cambie el valor del input, verificamos si es mayor a 30 y mostramos la alerta, de lo contrario la ocultamos. Aqui el codigo completo:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'main-component',
   template: `
<input
       type="number"
       min="0"
       id="obraAv"
       [value]="obraAv"
       ([ngModel])="obraInput"
       (ngModelChange)="obraChange()"
       class="form-control"
       placeholder="Avance de la obra"
       required="required"/>

<div *ngIf="showAlert" class="col-md-3 mb-2">
    <div class="alert alert-danger" ng-value="obraAv">
         <strong>Su obra civil no es asegurable</strong>
    </div>
</div>

`})
export class MainComponent
{
   obraAv : String;
   showAlert : Boolean;
   obraChange()
   {
      showAlert = parseInt(obraAv) > 30);
   }
}
```

Comment: Hola muchas gracias, pero aun tengo un problema, al colocar la funcion no detecta el showAlert y obraAv y les agregue un this. pero aun asi no me muestra la advertencia

  obraAv : string;
  showAlert : boolean;
  obraChange()
  {
    this.showAlert = parseInt(this.obraAv) > 30;
  }

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utiliza un *[(ngModel)]="variable"* para tener la variable del input en tu componente, así cada que haya un cambio, ejecutas la función de Alert()